# how to define a two field list on pyarrow.schema

Tags: list, mapping, field, pyarrow

I have a list object with this data:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 7654,
    "account_id": [
      17,
      "100.01.001 Cash"
    ]
  }
]
```

and I want to transfer this data into a pyarrow table, I created a schema for map every data type and field, for the field called "id" it just a data type int64 and I am able to map with this on schema the definition:
pa.field('id', pa.int64())

but for field "account_id" that is a list I need to map but I cannot get it, I have tried with all these ways but dont work:

```
pa.field('account_id',pa.list_(pa.list_(pa.int64(),pa.string())))
pa.field('account_id',pa.list_(pa.int64(), pa.list_(pa.string()))) 
pa.field('account_id',pa.list_(pa.int64(), pa.string()))
```

any suggestions I please you much

I need to find the way to map the list on schema based on data.

Comment: "account_id" is a list of heterogeneous data (a mix of string and ints). This is not supported in arrow.

Comment: @0x26res if convert list object to dict object the is there posibility for map the data?

Answer (score 0):

`account_id` is a list of heterogeneous data (a mix of string and ints). This is not supported in arrow.

You have a few options available if you want to represent your data differently.

1. Use a map:

```py
payload = [{"id": 7654, "account_id": {17: "100.01.001 Cash"}}]


schema = pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field("id", pa.int32()),
        pa.field("account_id", pa.map_(pa.int32(), pa.string())),
    ]
)
table = pa.Table.from_pylist(payload, schema)
```

2. Use a struct:

```
payload = [{"id": 7654, "account_id": {"id": 17, "description": "100.01.001 Cash"}}]

schema = pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field("id", pa.int32()),
        pa.field(
            "account_id",
            pa.struct(
                [
                    pa.field("id", pa.int32()),
                    pa.field("description", pa.string()),
                ]
            ),
        ),
    ]
)
table = pa.Table.from_pylist(payload, schema)
```

Comment: Thanks, @0x26res, I tried both options but don't work on them, I gonna try if converting onto an array object works.

Comment: Anyone else will have any suggestions for to solve this problem?